# Azure Function - c# - ServicebusTrigger with Blob binding

Tags: c#, python, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a python function with a servicebus trigger and a blob input binding. The name of the blob match the content of the queue message.
My function.json file looks like that:

```
{
"bindings": [
    {
    "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
    "name": "inputMessage",
    "connection": "Omnibus_Validation_Listen_Servicebus",
    "queueName": "validation-input-queue",
    "accessRights": "listen",
    "direction": "in"
    },
    {
    "type": "blob",
    "name": "inputBlob",
    "path": "baselines/{inputMessage}",
    "connection": "Omnibus_Blob_Storage",
    "direction": "in"
    }
],
"disabled": false
}
```

And it is working like a charm.

I'd to create a C# function with the same bindings but it does not seem to work.
I've used the same `function.json` file.

I have a `project.json` file:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "WindowsAzure.Storage": "8.5.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my `run.csx` file looks like that:

```
public static void Run(string inputMessage, Stream inputBlob, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {inputMessage}");
}
```

When I save/run the function, I received this error:

> Function ($import-baseline) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.import-baseline'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No binding parameter exists for 'inputMessage'.

Is there any difference between the python and c# sdk for this kind of binding ?

Comment: Looks ok. Try removing project.json, it's not needed in this case.

Comment: @Mikhail, Not working :-(

Comment: Yes... the problem is with `baselines/{inputMessage}` syntax. But funny that it works in python...

Comment: Yeah I know for queueTrigger the syntax is different, I tried `baselines/{inputMessage}` and it was working. I also tried `baselines/{serviceBusTrigger}` but no luck

Comment: @Thomas I have a question but different from what you asked. I just wanted to know how do you pass {inputMessage} named parameter when you send messages to queue. Do you have Python Example for this some where? I understood that this {inputMessage} should be a named parameter in the queue message. I insert the message using Python SDK and couldn't find any way to pass the named parameter.

Comment: @RajatArora it is a pretty old post, at that time, python was in experimental preview... Have you check the offcial documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python? Found this sample here: https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/queue-trigger-blob-in-out-binding

Answer (score 0):

I also can reproduce it on my side if I bind input blob path with `baselines\{serviceBusTrigger}` or `baselines\{inputMessage}` in the function.json file.

I am not sure whether it is supported to integrated input servicebus queue and input blob currently. We could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions) to Azure function team.

If Azure **storage queue** is acceptable we could use Azure storage queue trigger to do that. I test it on my side, it works correctly.

[image]

**run.csx file**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, Stream inputBlob, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# storage queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputBlob);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    log.Info(text);
}
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "path": "incontainer/{queueTrigger}",
      "connection": "testweblog_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "queueName": "myqueue",
      "connection": "testweblog_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I know that it is working with queueTrigger. Was wondering why it is working with Python and not with C# :-)

Comment: `Was wondering why it is working with Python and not with C#` I assume that it is not implemented in the C# currently, as they are different library.

Comment: you cannot do an input binding with servicebus queues